Can I write a C# lambda that mimics Is_Defined in Cosmos?
I can write select * from c where Not Is_Defined(c.Name) to get all documents that lack the Name property.
Is it possible to do as a C# lambda?
x => x.Name == null
does not work as the lambda is translated to a cosmosquery and becomes c.Name == null (or possibly Is_Null(c.Name) which always will be false for a non existing Name.

From this document, it states that "If a property isn't defined in an item, then its value is undefined. A property with the value null must be explicitly defined and assigned a null value.". In C# I am guessing this would translate to use of Reflection, for example something like .GetProperty(). I do not know how to use cosmos, and if that will translate as expected, so I don't think it would make sense for me to supply an answer

You can use the IsDefined extension on the property. It's part of the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq namespace when using the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos package.
using var iterator = container
    .GetItemLinqQueryable<Person>()
    .Where(p => !p.Name.IsDefined())
    .ToFeedIterator();

